# What is related_name used for?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, many-to-many

What is the `related_name` argument useful for on `ManyToManyField` and `ForeignKey` fields? For example, given the following code, what is the effect of `related_name='maps'`?

```
class Map(db.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='maps',
                                     verbose_name=_('members'))
```

Comment: @DanielRoseman Is it somehow good for performance or good practice to use related_name='+' when backwards relation is not necessary?

Comment: I'd be curious to know the answer to @lajarre's question.

Comment: @lajarre - I assume that won't change performance at all. I've had to use it once with FeinCMS content types. I personally think it's good practice to always specify the `related_name` so if you know you won't use it, I guess it's a good thing. That's a personal opinion of course.

Comment: @3cheesewheel it's in the docs now: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name `+` means do not create reverse relation

Comment: I noticed that once related_name is declated, object.modelname_set does not work.

Answer (score 890, accepted):

The `related_name` attribute specifies the name of the reverse relation from the `User` model back to your model.

If you don't specify a `related_name`, Django automatically creates one using the name of your model with the suffix `_set`, for instance `User.map_set.all()`.

If you *do* specify, e.g. `related_name=maps` on the `User` model, `User.map_set` will still work, but the `User.maps.` syntax is obviously a bit cleaner and less clunky; so for example, if you had a user object `current_user`, you could use `current_user.maps.all()` to get all instances of your `Map` model that have a relation to `current_user`.

The [Django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) has more details.

Comment: Okay, I know this is an old post. But I'm just trying to figure this out - what's the + trick at the end of the related name? For instance, what happens if I did `related_name='maps+'` in the example above?

Comment: if you add the +, django disables the mapping

Comment: for OneToOneField default related_name will be small case class name. For example in the given example if members would be OneToOnefield then "User.map" will work.

Comment: if you specify `related_name`, does `_set` still work in `django1.11 >` ??

Comment: I use Django 2.1.3 and I can note those are exclusive. Once `related_name` is specified, `_set` does not work anymore.

Answer (score 156):

To add to existing  answer - related name is a must in case there 2 FKs in the model that point to the same table. For example in case of Bill of material

```
@with_author 
class BOM(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    tomaterial =  models.ForeignKey(Material, related_name = 'tomaterial')
    frommaterial =  models.ForeignKey(Material, related_name = 'frommaterial')
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=10)
```

So when you will have to access this data 
you only can use related name

```
 bom = material.tomaterial.all().order_by('-creation_time')
```

It is not working otherwise (at least I was not able to skip the usage of related name in case of 2 FK's to the same table.)

Comment: You have to pick a related_name at least for one of them. The other one doesn't enecssarily require.

Comment: `related_name` should be plural. Because ForeignKey relations   return multiple objects.

Comment: sorry for the necro posting =) Mesut's comment has merit.  an example of what they are mentioning would be class Employee(models.Model):
    manager = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name = 'manages', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)
 google: "Django Tips #22 Designing Better Models" for more

Comment: I just saw this answer, and I'm relatively new to programming. Just wanted to ask that why would someone want to have multiple FKs pointing to the same table?
Why not just use the same FK everywhere?

Comment: This also covers the case where you have defined a ManyToMany on Model A pointing to Model B, whilst at the same time Model B has a ForeignKey pointing to Model A.

Comment: This answer is incorrect `related_name` should refer to the parent class, not the ForeignKey reference

Comment: @PyUnchained isn't that bad modeling?

Comment: @AdityaSingh imagine a 'product' table with two FKs to a 'location' table - one 'manufacture_location' and one 'warehouse_delivery_location'

Answer (score 34):

The `related_name` argument is also useful if you have more complex related class names. For example, if you have a foreign key relationship:

```
class UserMapDataFrame(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

In order to access `UserMapDataFrame` objects from the related `User`, the default call would be `User.usermapdataframe_set.all()`, which it is quite difficult to read.

Using the `related_name` allows you to specify a simpler or more legible name to get the reverse relation. In this case, if you specify `user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='map_data')`, the call would then be `User.map_data.all()`.

Answer (score 17):

The essentials of your question are as follows.

Since you have `Map` and `User` models and you have defined `ManyToManyField` in Map model, if you want to get access to ***members*** of the Map then you have the option of `map_instance.members.all()` since you have defined ***members*** field.
However, say you want to access all maps a user is a part of then what option do you have.

By default, Django provided you with `user_instance.modelname_set.all()` and this will translate to the `user.map_set.all()` in this case.

***maps*** is much better than ***map_set***.

**related_name** provides you an ability to let Django know how you are going to access Map from User model or in general how you can access reverse models which is the whole point in creating ManyToMany fields and using ORM in that sense.

Comment: Visit https://www.revsys.com/tidbits/tips-using-djangos-manytomanyfield/ for more information about ManyToMany field in Django

Answer (score 5):

The related name parameter is actually an option. If we do not set it, Django
automatically creates the other side of the relation for us. In the case of the Map model,
Django would have created a `map_set` attribute, allowing access via `m.map_set` in your
example(m being your class instance). The formula Django uses is the name of the model followed by the
string `_set`. The related name parameter thus simply overrides Django’s default rather
than providing new behavior.

Answer (score 1):

`prefetch_related` use for prefetch data for Many to many and many to one relationship data.
**`select_related` is to select data from a single value relationship.** Both of these are used to fetch data from their relationships from a model. For example, you build a model and a model that has a relationship with other models. When a request comes you will also query for their relationship data and Django has very good mechanisms To access data from their relationship like **`book.author.name`** but when you iterate a list of models for fetching their relationship data Django create each request for every single relationship data. To overcome this we do have  `prefetchd_related` and `selected_related`