# conflict between OneToMany and OneToOne relationship in Django

Tags: python, django

I need to define a Meeting model which includes an organiser and a number of participants. All participants are derived from the standard User in auth module.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Meeting(models.Model):
    organizer=models.ForeignKey(User)
    participants=models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

However, when running syncdb, the I got the following error

> Error: One or more models did not validate: hub.meeting: Accessor for
>   field 'organizer' clashes with related m2m field 'User.meeting_set'.
>   Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'organizer'.
>   hub.meeting: Accessor for m2m field 'participants' clashes with
>   related field 'User.meeting_set'. Add a related_name argument to the
>   definition for 'participants'.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: The title of this question doesn't have anything to do with the problem: I would suggest changing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
    organizer=models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="meetings_orginizer")
    participants=models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="meetings_participants")
```

If you have a user object and you want to follow the relationship backwards to find either *the meetings that user is an organizer of* or *meetings that the user is a participant of*, you need to specifically name a 'related_name' field on the model to distinguish them. Now you can follow the relationship backwards like so:

```
me = User.objects.get(id=0)
# Meetings I'm organising
m1 = me.meetings_orginizer.all()
# Meetings I'm participating in
m2 = me.meetings_participants.all()
```

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name
- [What is `related_name` used for in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-the-related-name-mean-in-django)

Answer (score 1):

the problem (as stated by the error message) has to do with backwards relations. when you define a foreign key (or many2many), django sets up a reverse relation User.meeting_set. however, since you have two relations, the reverse relations clash and you have to specify the related names manually. see the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

code as in answer above