# Django What is reverse relationship?

Tags: python, django

Can someone tell me what is reverse relationship means?
I have started using Django and in lot of places in the documentation I see 'reverse relationship, being mentioned. What is it exactly mean? why is it useful? What does it got to do with related_name in reference to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-the-related-name-mean-in-django) ?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Here is the documentation on [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)

Lets say you have 2 models

```
class Group(models.Model):
    #some attributes

class Profile(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    #more attributes
```

Now, from a profile object, you can do `profile.group`. But if you want the profile objects given the `group` object, How would you do that? Thats' where `related name` or the `reverse relationship` comes in.

Django, by defaults gives you a default `related_name` which is the ModelName (in lowercase) followed by `_set` -  In this case, It would be `profile_set`, so `group.profile_set`.

However, you can override it by specifying a `related_name` in the `ForeignKey` field.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='profiles')
    #more attributes
```

Now, you can access the foreign key as follows:

```
group.profiles.all()
```

Comment: So we can access,edit, query etc all the profile object attributes from group object or if you know the group_id?

Answer (score 5):

For a clearer picture you can assume that when we use reverse relationship, it adds an extra field in the referenced model:

For example:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
           name = models.CharField()
           email = models.EmailField()
class Salary(models.Model):
           amount = models.IntegerField()
           employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='salary')
```

After using related_name in Salary model, now you can assume the Employee model will have one more field: `salary`.

For example, the available fields would now be:

`name`, `email`, and `salary`

To find an employee, we can simply query in this way:

`e = Employee.objects.filter(some filter).first()`

To check their salary, we can check it by writing
`e.salary` (now we can use salary an attribute or field in employee model). This will give you the salary instance of that employee, and you can find the amount by writing `e.salary.amount`. This will give you the salary of that employee.

In case of many to many relationship we can use `.all()` and then iterate over that.

Answer (score 1):

In Django 2.0 you would define a ForeignKey as follows

```
mainclient = models.ForeignKey( MainClient, on_delete=model.CASCADE, related_name='+')
```

the `related_name='+'` would cancel the default reverse relationship that Django sets up, so in the previous example, you would not be able to query the profiles using `group.profiles.all()`.

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: If you had a Status object and a TransactionHistory object that has 2 relationships from TransactionHistory to Status, call them from_status and to_status.  Sure, you could give unique names to the reverse relationships in Status so you can access Status.transactionHistoriesFromStatuses and Status.transactionHistoriesToStatuses, but if your business logic would never use the reverse relationship then it would be reasonable to simply use '+' to remove the reverse relationship.