# How to set up double nested serializer in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to figure out how to set up my nested serializers.

```
# models.py

class Product(models.Model):
    sku = models.CharField()
    product_name = models.CharField()

class Order(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    address = models.CharField()

class OrderProduct(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey( Order )
    product = models.ForeignKey( Product )
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

So I want to have an api that can create an order in the form of the following:

```
{
  "name" : "James",
  "address" : "100 Main St",
  "products" : [
              { "sku" : "1234", "quantity" : 1 }
            ]
}
```

I understand that I would need nest OrderProductSerializer inside OrderSerializer, but how do I implement it here when the "products" data use the field "sku" which is not found in the OrderProduct model.  Do I do double-nesting?  How does that look like?

```
# serializers.py

class OrderProductSerializer( serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderProduct
        exclude = ()

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = OrderProductsSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        exclude = ()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to implement Nested Serialize on **reverse relationship**. So, you have to explicitly provide the relationship name as the parameter to the serializer via `source` argument.

Try this

```
class OrderProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderProduct
        fields = '__all__'


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = OrderProductSerializer(many=True, source='product_set')

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
```

For more info reffere these docs
1. [DRF Nested Relationship](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)
2. [DRF-Reverse Realation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#reverse-relations)
3. [What is `reverse-relationship` in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328910/django-what-is-reverse-relationship)