# What is article_set ? How does it works?

Tags: django, django-queryset

```
from django.db import models

class Reporter(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('headline',)
```

**Now in python shell:**

```
from datetime import date

r = Reporter(first_name='John', last_name='Smith', email='john@example.com'
r.save()

new_article = r.article_set.create(headline="John's second story",
pub_date=date(2005, 7, 29))
```

Above code is referenced from Django docs. If there is any misunderstanding please go to this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/).

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: You could also refer this SO post, [what-is-reverse-relationship in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328910/django-what-is-reverse-relationship)

Comment: Thanks @ blhsing . Now i know what does it means.

Answer (score 1):

`article_set` is a backward relation to the articles from your reporter object.
Django creates this "hidden" fields because of the ForeignKey `reporter` in your `Article` model.

See [this part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) of the doc.

> If a model has a ForeignKey, instances of the foreign-key model will
>   have access to a Manager that returns all instances of the first
>   model. By default, this Manager is named FOO_set, where FOO is the
>   source model name, lowercased. This Manager returns QuerySets, which
>   can be filtered and manipulated as described in the “Retrieving
>   objects” section above.

You can access the `reporter` from an article instance like this:

```
article_instance.reporter
```

And you can access the articles from a reporter like this:

```
reporter_instance.article_set.all()
```