# django rest framework serializers giving "serializers.Language.None"

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Here is my serializers.py

```
class GetCompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    language = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('company_name','started_from','country','email','website','ip','active','language')
```

here is my views.py

```
class CompanyView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset =  Company.objects.all()
serializer_class = CompanySerializer

def get_serializer_class(self):
    serializer_class = self.serializer_class
    if self.request.method == 'GET':
        serializer_class = GetCompanySerializer
    return serializer_class
```

Here is my models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_id   = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    started_from = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    country      = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email        = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    website      = models.URLField()
    ip           = models.GenericIPAddressField(default=get_ip(),null=True,blank=True)
    active       = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name

class Language(models.Model):
    language_id     = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    language_name   = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    language_logo   = models.FileField()
    created_on      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    latest_build_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    latest_version  = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    company         = models.ForeignKey('Company',on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='language')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.language_name
```

giving api:

```
[
    {
        "company_name": "Guido van dom rossum",
        "started_from": "2018-10-03T04:58:54.889132Z",
        "country": "Netherland",
        "email": "help@python.com",
        "website": "https://python.org",
        "ip": "127.0.0.1",
        "active": true,
        "language": "serializers.Language.None"
    }
]
```

it should give the language name for language field bit it is giving "serializers.Language.None" instead.

please have a look into this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since **`language`** is a [***reverse relation***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328910/django-what-is-reverse-relationship) it shouldn't be a **`CharField`**. So you have to define a **`LanguageSerializer()`** and map it in your **`GetCompanySerializer`** as below,

```
class LanguageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Language


class GetCompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    language = LanguageSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('company_name', 'started_from', 'country', 'email', 'website', 'ip', 'active', 'language')
```

---

If you wish to get the **`__str__()`** reprwesentation of ***`Language`*** model, use [**`StringRelatedField()`**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield) instead of **`CharField()`**

```
class GetCompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    language = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
```

class Meta:
    model = Company
    fields = ('company_name', 'started_from', 'country', 'email', 'website', 'ip', 'active', 'language')</code></pre>

Comment: this way it is giving         "language": [
                                               "python"
                                            ]

but i am expecting   "language": "python"

Comment: @KiranSyoutubechannel It's because of each company instance is related to ***one or more `Language`s***.

Comment: You can do it somehow but it *may* raise some confusion for you. (since it has more than one language, which language instance should return at this time?)