# my profile object is not getting serialized in the user serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am using Django rest auth to authenticate my users, that works well. how my model is set up is that I have the custom user model for authentication and I also have a profile model that gets created with a signal.

I want that when the users are fetched in its URL, the profile for that user is also called an object in user.

my models.py (I didnt include some models like the user managers, skill, e.t.c as i felt they werent relevant)

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['fullname']

    objects = UserManager()


class Profile(models.Model):
    '''
    Note:
    profile photo is expecting photos link gotten from cloudnairy from the frontend
    - The height is calculated in feets and inches
    - Need to sort out location (lives in)
    - Need to add an age function
    - Need to add achievemnet as a foreign field 
    - Need to add education also as a foreign field
    - Add follow functionality
    '''
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, verbose_name="DOB", null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    profile_photo = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=300, null=True)
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX, blank=True, null=True)
    type_of_body = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=BODYTYPE, blank=True, null=True)
    feet = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    inches = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    lives_in = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

the serializers.py code

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = "__all__"

        read_only_fields = ('pk',)


class CustomUserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    profile = ProfileSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('pk', 'email', 'fullname', 'profile')
        read_only_fields = ('email', 'fullname', 'profile')
```

view.py

```
class ListUsersView(APIView):

    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def get(self, request):
        user = User.objects.all()
        serializer = CustomUserDetailsSerializer(user, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^list-users/$', ListUsersView.as_view(), name='list-users'),
```

the JSON response i get

```
[
    {
        "pk": 1,
        "email": "opeyemiodedeyi@gmail.com",
        "fullname": "opeyemiodedeyi"
    },
    {
        "pk": 2,
        "email": "odedeyiopeyemi94@gmail.com",
        "fullname": "opeyemi odedeyi"
    }
]
```

how do I get the profiles to show in the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Method-1

Use [**`source`** (DRF doc)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) argument

```
class CustomUserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer(read_only=True, source="profile_set")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('pk', 'email', 'fullname', 'profile')
        read_only_fields = ('email', 'fullname', 'profile')
```

Since **Profile** is in reverse relation with **User**, you need to specify the **reverse lookup**, which is **`profile_set`**

### Method-2

Change [**`related_name`** (Django doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) in models,

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    ...
```

---

### Recommended Changes

```
# models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profiles')
    ...


# serializers.py
class CustomUserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profiles = ProfileSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('pk', 'email', 'fullname', 'profiles')
        read_only_fields = ('email', 'fullname', 'profiles')
```

### References

1. [What is reverse relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328910/django-what-is-reverse-relationship)
2. [Django: Many-To-One Relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

Comment: thanks for this, but which of these two methods would you recommend to use?

Comment: I would recommend changing the related_name to **`profiles`** (see, it's plural) and use the same related name in serializer also, since `Users` can have multiple `profiles` according to your DB structure.

Comment: for some reason it isn't working for me, please could you show what to change in the serializer, Thank you

Comment: okay, it kinda works now, but all the fields are showing null. that is the current problem

Comment: Please ask a new question since your new question and OP are different