# Generating django admin and foreignkey error

Tags: python, django

Here is my model.py :

```
class MireilleUser(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField( blank=True, editable=False,default=timezone.now)
    modified = models.DateTimeField( blank=True,default=timezone.now)
    uuid = models.CharField(blank=True,  max_length=48,default='')
    firebase_id = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ On save, update timestamps """
        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()
        self.modified = timezone.now()
        if not self.uuid:
            self.uuid = str(uuid.uuid4().hex) + str(random.randint(1000, 9999))
        return super(MireilleUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    
class MireilleAppSubscription(models.Model):
    ACTIVE = 'AC'
    SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
    JUNIOR = 'JR'
    SENIOR = 'SR'
    GRADUATE = 'GR'
    STATUS_VALUE = [
        (ACTIVE, 'Active'),
        ('SO', 'Sophomore'),
        ('JR', 'Junior'),
        ('SR', 'Senior'),
        ('GR', 'Graduate'),
    ]
    STRIPE = 'ST'
    GOOGLE = 'GO'
    APPLE = 'AP'
    PLATFORM_VALUE = [
        (STRIPE, 'STRIPE'),
        (GOOGLE, 'GOOGLE'),
        (APPLE, 'APPLE'),
    ]
    created = models.DateTimeField( blank=True, editable=False,default=timezone.now)
    modified = models.DateTimeField( blank=True,default=timezone.now)
    uuid = models.CharField(blank=True,  max_length=48,default='')
    mireille_user = models.ForeignKey(MireilleUser,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    date_begin = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, editable=True, default=timezone.now)
    stripe_client_id = models.CharField(blank=True,  max_length=48,default='')
    platform = models.CharField(blank=True,  max_length=2,choices=PLATFORM_VALUE)
    expected_end_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, editable=True, default=(timezone.now()+timezone.timedelta(days=8)))
    is_free = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_vip = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    promo_code = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=128, default='')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2,
        choices=STATUS_VALUE,
        default=ACTIVE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ On save, update timestamps """
        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()
        self.modified = timezone.now()
        if not self.uuid:
            self.uuid = str(uuid.uuid4().hex) + str(random.randint(1000, 9999))
        return super(MireilleAppSubscription, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And here is my admin.py :

```
class MireilleUser_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [field.name for field in MireilleUser._meta.get_fields()]
    search_fields = [field.name for field in MireilleUser._meta.get_fields()]
    actions = [
        export_as_csv_action(
            "CSV Export",
            fields=[field.name for field in MireilleUser._meta.get_fields()],
        )
    ]


class MireilleAppSubscription_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [field.name for field in MireilleAppSubscription._meta.get_fields()]
    search_fields = [field.name for field in MireilleAppSubscription._meta.get_fields()]
    actions = [
        export_as_csv_action(
            "CSV Export",
            fields=[field.name for field in MireilleAppSubscription._meta.get_fields()],
        )
    admin.site.register(MireilleUser, MireilleUser_Admin)
    admin.site.register(MireilleAppSubscription, MireilleAppSubscription_Admin)
```

but in the admin when i click on Mireille User on the admin i have :

```
AttributeError at /admin/AppUser/mireilleuser/
Unable to lookup 'mireilleappsubscription' on MireilleUser or MireilleUser_Admin
```

I don't understand why because the foreignkey is in MireilleAppSubscription to MireilleUser and not MireilleUser To MireilleAppSubscription

i doubt that there is something in my way of using meta fields for genrating the admin.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The is because of Django creating a [*reverse relation*--(Django What is reverse relationship?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328910/django-what-is-reverse-relationship) named ***`mireilleappsubscription`*** and which is not a ***actual field***

I would suggest using the **`list_display`** and **`search_fields`** by specifying each field one-by-one

```
class MireilleUser_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["created", "modified", "ect"]
    search_fields = ["created", "modified", "etc"]
```

**OR**

If you want just to igore the error, remove the **`mireilleappsubscription`** field from the list as,

```
fields = [field.name for field in MireilleUser._meta.get_fields()]
fields.remove("mireilleappsubscription")


class MireilleUser_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = fields
    search_fields = fields
```

Comment: Can you help me with my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64520274/show-related-data-inside-foreign-key-object-in-django-admin