# Show related data inside foreign key object in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am creating a school management system. Multiple users/school_owners will create multiple classes according to the number of classes in their school. I am the superuser [i.e. Super Admin] that can access classes in every school. So, I want to link classes of a particular school [i.e. Foreign Key] in particular link. And I'll press that link and the class linked with the foreign key will be display in the list.

It should be like this inside `admin`:

- ***School Name 1***
- ---- Class 1
- ---- Class 2
- ---- Class 3
- ---- Class 4
- ***School Name 2***
- ---- Class 1
- ---- Class 2
- ---- Class 3
- ---- Class 4

Here `school name 1` and `school name 2` are the foreign keys value. And when I click in `school name 1` and `school name 2` they should redirect me to their respective classes...

Inside models.py

```
from django.db import models
from accounts.models import school_details

class student_class(models.Model):
    connect_school = models.ForeignKey(school_details, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    class_list = models.CharField(max_length=95)
    def __str__(self):
            return self.class_list
```

So, `connect_school` [i.e. `school name`] should be display first in the `admin` and when we click in `school name` the `classes` of that particular school should be displayed.

Inside admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from school.models import student_class
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(student_class)
```

This photo denotes how that data is being displayed in an unorganized way with the upper `admin.py`.

[image: show related data inside the foreign key object in Django admin]

Comment: Please Have a look, it should work like this. https://imgur.com/a/Ul5JTvM. When I click in 'test school' it should redirect to it's respective class.

Comment: Use `inlines` the admin class

Answer (score 2):

The least hacky way to solve this, in my opinion, are [admin inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects). Instead of pointing to another admin page, which kind of goes against the Django Admin structure, you can add inline editing interfaces for each class.

```
# admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from accounts.models import school_details
from school.models import student_class


class ClassInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = student_class


class SchoolDetailsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = school_details
    inlines = [ClassInline, ]


admin.site.register(school_details, SchoolDetailsAdmin)
```

Comment: This did nothing except schowing `school_details` model.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 def __str__(self):
        return self.class_list
```

to

```
 def __str__(self):
        return "[%s] %s" % (self.connect_school.name, self.class_list)
```

(assuming connect_school has `name` attribute)

Comment: Bro, this display the huge list classes with their respective `school name` in brackets. that's not what I wanted. I want to display the school name at first and when I click in that school name their respective classes should be displayed. Can you help me with this requirement. Thanks anyway. Waiting for response

Comment: Have a look, it should work like this. https://imgur.com/a/Ul5JTvM