# Django Querying chained Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

Hello I am learning Django ORM queries and come to figure out reverse relationship in Foreign Key. I cannot visualize _set in foreign key field hope I will be cleared here. Here are my model I have been working.

```
class Location(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        validators=[validate_location_name],
        unique=True,
    )
```

I have Route model linked with Location as FK:

```
class Route(BaseModel):
    departure = models.ForeignKey(
        Location,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='route_departure'
    )
    destination = models.ForeignKey(
        Location,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='route_destination'
    )
```

Similarly I have `Bus Company Route` linked Foreign key with `Route`

```
class BusCompanyRoute(BaseModel):
    route = models.ForeignKey(Route, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Finally I have `Schedule` Model linked with `BusCompanyRoute` as `Fk`

```
class Schedule(BaseModel):
    bus_company_route = models.ForeignKey(BusCompanyRoute, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Problem is I want to query from views being on Schedule model want to  link with `departure` and `destination` how will I do that? I have only done this so far on `view.py`

`schedule = Schedule.objects.all()`

I am stuck on querying Chained foreign key

Comment: What exactly you are trying to get, it is unclear can you elaborate with example

Comment: I want to query `departure ` and `destination` from `Schedule`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply try like this:

```
Schedule.objects.filter(bus_company_route__route__departure__name="A", bus_company_route__route__destination__name="B")
```

For more information, please see [how you can follow lookup in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

Comment: one query:  all foreign key above were one to many so that is reason we applied `bus_company_route__route__departure__name ='A'` ? PS: can you help me linking documentation for this concept.

Comment: Sure. Documentation link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Answer (score 1):

I am continuing from your code, as everything looks fine

```
schedule = Schedule.objects.all()

for s in schedule:
    current_schedule_route = s.bus_company_route.route
    departure = current_schedule_route.destination.name
    destination = current_schedule_route.destination.name
    print(departure, '->', destination)
```

you don't need reverse relation to query departure and destination from Schedule

an easy explaination of reverse relation along with its use case can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328910/django-what-is-reverse-relationship)