# how to filter based on created an object for froingkey django

Tags: python, django, filter

i have two models (tables) `Ticketing` and `Cancel`

```
class Ticketing(models.Model):
    a= models.CharField(max_length=40)
    b = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    #others

class Cancel(models.Model):
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticketing,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="ticket")
    #others
```

views.py , i have to make a query to show all active `Ticketing`

```
Ticketing.objects.filter()#how to filter all objects which `cancel` not created for
```

thank you , i know make a boolean field then whenver cancel created `BooleanField` in `Ticketing` will be False , but i dont want to use it , is it possible please ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter active Ticketing instances with lookup **isnull**.

```
Ticketing.objects.filter(ticket__isnull=True)
```

Comment: did this solution worked? there is no field called ticket in ticketing @HunarMohammed

Comment: `tickting` field is in the `Cancel` table

Comment: @umair it is reverse connection from Cencel to Ticketing

Comment: yes, but you query the Ticketing model here. is there a related_name or something there?

Comment: take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328910/django-what-is-reverse-relationship @umair

Comment: You can use related_name for the name to use for the relation from the related object back to this one.