# How to filter out objects that do not have a relationship with another form in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have two samples in an application built using Django:

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()

class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I want to filter out all users who don't have any products in the store.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems the simplest:

```py
user_ids_with_product = [product.user_id for product 
                         in Product.objects.all()]
Users.objects.exclude(id__in=user_ids_with_product)
```

Comment: Can you explain that?

Comment: First you take all user ids that have a product, then you use those in an exclude query (kind of filter but in reverse) - you take all Users, but exclude those that have a product.

Answer (score 3):

User's model can access Product's objects,  for this situation you can filter all users that product_set is null,
`User.objects.filter(product__isnull=True)`

Comment: I think this would result in an error. `product_set` is not a field defined on the User model.

Comment: when you create foreignkey, Django gets a new API on the other side (reverse relation)
 by default <model name>_set name. in this question, user's object has a product_set that contains all user's products. you can read this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17328910/8157102 for more information

Comment: Yes, while that is true, the reverse relation cannot be used in a filter query.

Comment: I have just checked this myself. Like I said above, the reverse relation cannot be used like this. However, you could do something like: `User.objects.filter(product__user__isnull=True)`

Comment: Tnx for your feedback, I edit the answer, we can use ```User.objects.filter(product__isnull=True)``` I test that is OK. if you want, test it and say the result