# Foreign key not available on object

Tags: django

Very very beginner question that puzzles me. I have problems showing the foreign key ArtWorkImages in my template, so i wanted to debug it in the view, but the foreign key ArtworkImage is not available on Artwork:

my model:

```
from django.db import models

class Artwork(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class ArtworkImage(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey(Artwork, related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = "images/")
```

the view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from erikheide.models import Artwork
from erikheide.models import ArtworkImage

def index(request):
    artworks = Artwork.objects.all()[:5]

    artwork = artworks[0]

    images = artwork.artworkimage_set.all()

    context = {'latest_poll_list': artworks}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

the error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
> line 115, in get_response
>     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "/home/fhp/Hentede filer/tastypie/django15/erikheide/views.py",
> line 13, in index
>     images = artwork.artworkimage_set.all() AttributeError: 'Artwork' object has no attribute 'artworkimage_set'
```

The template that did not work (no images turn up)

```
{% if artworks %}
    <ul>
    {% for artwork in artworks %}
        <li><a href="{{ artwork.title }}/">{{ artwork.body}}</a></li>

        {% for image in artwork.images_set.all %}
        <img src="{{ image.image.url }}">

        {% endfor %}

    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No artworks are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined a [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) on the `ForeignKey` field, you need to use it to follow the relationship.

Replace:

```
images = artwork.artworkimage_set.all()
```

with:

```
images = artwork.images.all()
```

Also see: [What is `related_name` used for in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for-in-django)

Comment: Thanks, it worked just fine. I guess i must have found some old documentation since i used the _set syntax.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
artwork.images.all()
```

instead

```
artwork.artworkimage_set.all()
```

`image_set` is default name for RelatedManager. If `related_name` specified with foreign key RelatedManager name redefines.