# what exactly is related_name in django? where is the backward relationship located?

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Comment(models.Model):

user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='st_comments')
```

I have the above class in models.py .

```
related_name
```

has the backward relationship to what? st_comments?

What exactly is st_comments and where is it located and how is it related?
Is it a field entry in another class?

If you need more info [please check this](https://github.com/nitely/Spirit/blob/master/spirit/comment/models.py#L31)

I've been through [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for-in-django#2642645)

Comment: Rather than looking at other questions, did you [read the official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)? What is unclear?

Comment: I already read this.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Comment: OK, so what's not clear?

Comment: from the official docs.

related_name="tags"

Where is "tags" located?

Comment: I'm sorry I really don't understand what you're asking here. The [other doc page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) you linked to showed **exactly** where it is used. Why is this confusing?

Comment: I searched the models.py file and other related files for 'st_comments' , as it is backward related. It must be somewhere in other models. But there's nowhere in the entire app st_comments is mentioned. So what's it doing?

Thank you so much sir. Hope this is helpful

Comment: No, it is *defined in the code you've given*. That is where it is defined. Why would it be anywhere else?

Comment: It won't appear in your code anywhere, it is field added by django on runtime into another model, so you can access your relation in reversed direction - from related model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`st_comments` will be located inside User model (or other model provided in `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`) and it will contain queryset to all comments assigned to particular user.

Comment: Your comment helped me most. Thank you