# Access to models with a foreign key in the template

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-templates

I have a `profile` model with a one-to-one relationship to the `User` model so I can access to both models in the templates tanks to the `user` variable like this:

```
template.html

{% if user.profile.phone == 1234567890 %}
    Show something
{% endif %}
```

That works fine, the condition gives `True` and show something but I have too the models `Property` and `User_Property`, the `User_Property` model have as `Foreignkey` the ids from `User` and `Property`.

```
models.py

class Property(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class User_Property(models.Model):
    us = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='up_us')
    prop = models.ForeignKey(Property, related_name='up_prop')
```

So if I try to access to the `User_Property` model like this:

```
{% if user.user_property.prop == 1 %}
    Show something
{% endif %}
```

I can't access it shows nothing like it was `False` even when it's `True`, I have tried with `user.user_property.prop_id == 1` too. It is beacause the relationship with the `Profile` model was made with the `OneToOneField` and the relationship with `User_Property` was made with the `ForeignKey` field and I need to pass in the `context` the `User_Property` model?

And it is possible to access to `Property` model like if I use a `JOIN` SQL statement in the template? something like this:

```
{% if user.user_property.property.name == 'the name of the property' %}
    Show something
{% endif %}
```

Sorry for the long Post but I tried to add all the need info.

**EDIT:** Ok if someone need something similar this is what I did to solve the problem.

Create a `context_processor.py` to return a instance of `User_Property` and add it to my `settings.py` in this way I can access to the instance in all my templates even if I don't pass it as context in the views.

```
context_processors.py

from App_name.models import User_Property
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def access_prop(request):
    user = request.user.id #add the .id to no have problems with the AnonymousUser in my logg-in page
    user_property = User_Property.objects.filter(us=user).values_list('prop', flat=True) #this stores the list of all the properties for the logg-in user
    return {
        'user_property': user_property,
    }

settings.py

from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += ('App_name.context_processors.access_prop',)
```

Then in the template check if the user have a especific property

```
template.html

{% if 'property name' in user_property %}
    Show something
{% else %}
    This is not for you
{% endif %}
```

To can check in especific for the `name` instead of the `id` just add `to_field='name'` in my prop field in the model `User_Property` like this: `prop = models.ForeignKey(Property, related_name='up_prop', to_field='name')`.

Comment: It's hard to follow. Do you have `OneToOneField` relationship or not? What do you pass to the context as `user`?

Comment: The `OneToOneField` relationship are between `User` and `Profile` models and the `user` is an instance of the `User` model from the the currently logged-in user https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#users

Comment: And piece of advice, it's better not to name your class `Property`, it is reserved name(in lowercase).

Comment: @vishes_shell Don't worry that's just the name I use in this example not the real name I use for my class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

You should use the `related_name` that you set in the `ForeignKey` and the built-in methods of the relationships:

try this:

```
user.up_us.filter(prop__name="the name")
```

**EDIT**

for using the `.filter(prop__name="the name")` method you have to do it in a `.py` file.

Comment: Gives me `TemplateSyntaxError Could not parse the remainder: '(prop__name="the name")' from 'user.up_us.filter(prop__name="the name")'`

Comment: Do it in the views.py and pass it in the context.

Comment: Can I do that if the elements wich I apply the condition are from my base.html template and don't use a view to pass context?

Comment: Sure, take a view to context processors in django  -> [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors)

Comment: Thanks @arcegk, just created my own context_processor to have access to the instance of `User_Property` in my base.html

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try: `{% if user.user_property.prop.id == 1 %}`

Comment: @M.Gar Try printin `{{user.user_property}}` I think this has no value.

Comment: @M.Gar You need to use `up_us` because this is a reverse relationship.

Comment: ok using the `{{user.up_us}}` shows me `App.User_Property.None` that's I think that indicates that now have ccess to that model.

Comment: @M.Gar Yes, but keep in mind that could be many `User_Property` objects pointing to the same `User` object, so when you call `user.up_us` it will give you a set not an object, you can test this in your view using `request.user.up_us.all()`

Comment: but how can I use that to create the condition that I need?

Comment: @M.Gar You can choose the `User_Property` in your view and send it to the view: `request.user.up_us.get(pk=1)` this will give the `User_Property` object with `id=1`, add it to your context and use it in your template.

Answer (score 1):

You've set `related_name` in `us = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='up_us')`, so you need to use it

```
{% if user.up_us.prop.name == 'the name of the property' %}
    Show something
{% endif %}
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2642645/3124746) has a good explanation of how to use and what `related_name` for.

And try to exclude to much logic from templates.

Comment: Tried with the `related_name` but nothing

Comment: @M.Gar can you try to `print(request.user.up_us.prop.name)` in your _view_. Because i think there is no way that this can work in other way. Be sure that your user is authenticated and there is `User_Property` which related to current user and have desired `prop` with needed `name`.