# Django api making list of fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a API that has **repeated number of fields** for same posts

[image]

Though **comments** belongs to **same title**, they are divided into **different object**. I wanted to make comments to be a list like `"comments": ["hi1","hi2","hi3","hi4","ads"]` not sure how to achieve this. Everything to be in **single dictionary**

My model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description=models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def description_as_list(self):
        return self.description.split('\n')

class Comment(models.Model):
    title=models.ForeignKey(Post)
    comments=models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.title)
```

serializer

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.CharField(source="title.id", read_only=True)
    title = serializers.CharField(source="title.title", read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('id','title','comments')


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id','title','description','pub_date')
```

views.py

```
class CommentList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer

class CommentDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
```

What could be done to make a list?

Any help is much appreciated..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Because comments only make sense for a given post, I would suggest getting rid of the CommentList and instead simply add the comments as the list you want, on each post. You can easily do this by changing your PostSerializer:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comments = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id','title','description','pub_date', 'comments')

    def get_comments(self, obj):
        comment_list = obj.comment_set.all()
        data = []
        for comment in comment_list:
            data.append(comment.comments)
        return data
```

This should add a list of comments on every post.

Let me know if this wasn't exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: You can get rid of read_only=True. That's default for SerializerMethodField I guess.

Comment: @davka...I think there is some problem with line      ......data.append(comment.comments).............my IDE says it cannot look for comments

Comment: comments should automatically be added by django when you use `title=models.ForeignKey(Post)` in your model. Your IDE may not understand django. Try changing the model to `title=models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments')`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for-in-django

Comment: Edited my answer with comments_set, but I prefer to use related_name not to have to remember what Django uses

Comment: @davka........thanks for helping me buddy..........no it didnot work...given ..... 'for comment in comments:'......what does comments have to loop.....you should declare it right?...I hope you are missing something........

Comment: Sorry, when I did the last edit, I missed one spot. It should iterate over the query with comments which I assigned to comment_list