# Django Queryset: filtering by related item manager

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have model for pages that consist of a number of content blocks.

```
class Page(models.Model):
    ...

class Block(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page)
    ...
```

The `Block` has a handful of other properties that determine whether it is considered to be "active" or not (a couple booleans and a datetime field). I have a manager for the `Block` model so that I can get a list of active Blocks

```
Block.objects.active()
Page.objects.first().block_set.active()
```

I want to be able to write a queryset to return only `Page` objects that have active blocks. I would like to do this using the existing `Block` active manager, so that I am only defining what makes an "active" block once (DRY). IE something like:

```
Page.objects.annotate(count=Count('block__active')).filter(count__gt=0)
```

Obviously that does not work since `active` is not a property of `Block`. Is there a way I can use the existing `Block` manager to achieve this?

Comment: Is all the data necessary to compute `active()` stored in the database? Because when it is you can use that logic to build an annotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per what I know, there is no way to achieve it using single `queryset`, since you want to use the `active()` available within your manager. But you may achieve the result by adding the [related name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for-in-django) to `Page` in `Block` model as:

```
class Block(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page, related_name='related_block')
    ...
```

Now your code should be:

```
active_blocks = Block.objects.active()  # Queryset with all active blocks
# Queryset of Pages with Block in 'active_blocks' 
active_pages = Page.objects.filter(related_block__in=active_blocks)
```

Now on this QuerySet, you may perform `annonate` or whatever you desire which is allowed on `Page`'s QuerySet.

Comment: Doing it with 2 queries like that makes sense. Thanks. I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a boolean field on the model, something like `is_active`, and update it on `save()` or `set_active()`? Then you'll be able to query your Model by that field.

Comment: One of the fields is a datetime field. Whether the model is active or not depends partly on the value of that field and the current time, so I have to evaluate it every time I load an object.

Comment: Hm. From what you've described, it looks like that you define if the block is active using `is_active()` method on a class. Doesn't it mean that unless it's called, your Block's active/inactive state stays the same unless changed?