# newbie - understanding Django's class-based views dynamic filtering

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to follow and learning about dynamic filtering in Django from the docs. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering
I've just been following along step by step and copy/pasted the code from docs. But I don't understand the last bit about added the publisher into the context, meaning I can't figure out how to query that data in the template. The only thing I can get a "hold" of publisher.

Because in the PublisherDetail view `publisher_detail.html` you would just do something straight forward like this, to list all the books from a publisher:

```
{% for book in book_list %}
    {{ book.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

---

This is part that is tripping me up.

> We can also add the publisher into the context at the same time, so we
>   can use it in the template:

```
# ...

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # Call the base implementation first to get a context
    context = super(PublisherBookList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # Add in the publisher
    context['publisher'] = self.publisher
    return context
```

Comment: It's not clear where you are having trouble and what you are asking about, unfortunately. What *exactly* is "tripping you up" about this?

Comment: I guess I misunderstood, what exactly was supposed to happen. So it was my own reading and comprehension skills that were "tripping my up". I apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `context['publisher'] = self.publisher` in `get_context_data` means you can display the publisher's details in the context. For example, you could display the publisher's name above the list of book titles with:

```
<h2>Books published by {{ publisher.name }}</h2>

{% for book in book_list %}
    {{ book.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access related objects as described here: [What is `related_name` used for in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for-in-django) .

Try calling either `publisher.books.all()` or `publisher.book_set.all()`:

```
{% for book in publiser.book_set.all %}
    {{ book.title }}
{% endfor %}
```