# What's the best to make a tree of comments in django

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

I've made a model of comments with a prarent field to store a comment as a child of other one.

My question is how to display it in template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I've written this on mobile but I hope you can work it out
BTW
This is from my own app

let's say you wanna make something like Instagram where every nested comment has a reply button they all would appear under elder_most comment.

This is a weird approach but you can also make every nested button's reply button submit to the elder most comment. This approach is when each reply button refers to its real parent

This is just for your understanding

```
make a model
Comments
Parent : MantToMany(self refername = child null=true)
User:  ForeignKey(user)
Text: TextField
Likes: ForeignKey(comments_likes)
Post: ForeignKey(Posts)
```

I've made a function which gets the oldest comment and saves it in the oldest

```
Def  Eldermost_comment(comment):
    If comment.parent is none:
        pass
    Else:
        comment_ = Eldermost_comment(comment.parent)
        comment.parent = comment_
```

call it in presave signal, this would give every nested comment same parent

```
Queryset = comments.objects.all.filter(post=123456)
```

and it's so easy

just using referring name get all the child comments.

```
for comment in Queryset:
    if comment.child is none:
        #just display comment

    else:
        #display comment and then
        #display comment.child.all()
```

Comment: This is by far the weirdest and the best answer I've ever had

thanks for your help Bruh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the related name field to get the child comments . On the template you will be having two for loops. First for loops iterate through each parent comments and the second one iterate through the chillds of that parent element. For eg:`for comment in comments :
For child_comment in comment.related_name.all():
Print child_comment`

[What is `related_name` used for in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for-in-django)