# Accessing the parent object pointing to children objects in Many-to-Many Relationship Django

Tags: django

I have the following models below:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course)

class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Can I access the account object pointing to a course from a course? Say for example:

```
course = Course.objects.get(id=1)

account_parent = course.parent_pointing_to_me
```

Comment: With a many-to-many fields, by definition you can have *many* "parents pointing to me". If you just want one, you should use a ForeignKey instead.

Comment: Do yu find the answer?

Comment: Yes @reza_khalafi . You may refer to the answer here in this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2642645/4826123

Basically, you need to access it via the `related_name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get list of accout related to the class using `account_set` attribute (see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships)):

```
account_parents = course.account_set.all()
```

Since `account_set` is related manager, you can use any other queryset method, for example if you need first account in the list:

```
account_parent = course.account_set.first()
```

Comment: what if I want to get only those courses that don't have any account ID ?

Comment: @ZainKhan you can try to filter it like this `Course.objects.filter(account__isnull=True)`. Check this doc for more details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Comment: what is SET? this is not work