# Display answer in a Django website

Tags: django

I work on a small app in Django, a website where a student puts a question using a form and the teacher will answer from admin site. The problem is that I can not display the answer and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
I attach models, template and view.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.db.models import CASCADE

    class Question(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
        question_content = models.TextField()
        date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=datetime.now)

        class Meta:
            ordering = ('-date',)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title


    class Answer(models.Model):
        question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='answers', on_delete=CASCADE)
        answer_content = models.TextField()
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

        class Meta:
            ordering = ('-created',)

        def __str__(self):
            return 'Answer to {}'.format(self.question)
```

views.py

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, PageNotAnInteger, EmptyPage
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.views.generic import ListView

from registration.forms import RegistrationForm, QuestionForm
from registration.models import *


def question(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

        questions = Question.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'posturi.html', {'question': questions})

    else:
        # if post request is not true, returning blog
        form = QuestionForm()
        return render(request, 'blog.html', {'form': form})



def question_list(request):
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    answers = question.answers //  this is the problem i can not solve


    paginator = Paginator(questions, 6)  # 6 question in each page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        questions = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer deliver the first page
        questions = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range deliver last page of results
        questions = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'posturi.html', {'question': questions, 'answer': answers})
```

posturi.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    {% for questions in question %}
        <div class=" card ">
            <div class="card-header"><h3>{{ questions.title }} :</h3></div>
            <hr>
            <div class="card-text">{{ questions.question_content | linebreaks }}</div>
            <div class="card-footer"><h4>{{ questions.date }}</h4></div>
            {% for answers in question.answer_set.all %}
                <div class="card-header"><h3>Raspuns la  : "{{ answers.question.title }}"</h3></div>
                <hr>
                <div class="card-text">{{ answers.answer_content | linebreaks }}</div>
                <div class="card-footer"><h4>{{ answers.created }}</h4></div>
                {% empty %}
                <div class="card-text"><h4>Fara raspuns.</h4></div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

The error i get is : 'function' object has no attribute 'answer'. Can anyone help me to understand how to display the answers? I read a lot of articles but nothing helped.
Thanks.

Comment: This is literally the structure from the official tutorial. Have you read through that? Why not?

Comment: Plus, you don't even need that line; you don't need to send `answers` to the template separately as you are already iterating through the related set in the template.

Comment: I did this, but no answer appears on the page.

Answer (score 0):

It should be question.answers.all() instead of just question.answers. For further information, you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for-in-django).

Answer (score 0):

`question` is the function you have defined in your `views.py` which is why the error says

> 'function' object has no attribute 'answer'

You probably want to use **questions** defined in the previous line

```
def question_list(request):
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    answers = questions.answers
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time; finally i find the right answer:
to get the answers displayed i use 'select_related()' like in :

def question_list(request):
questions = Question.objects.all()
answers = Answer.objects.select_related()

return render(request, 'posturi.html', {'question': questions, 'answer': answers}

and in template :
{% for answers in answer %}
....
{% endfor %}

Maybe someone need this.