# Not getting foreign key data in django api views

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Currently I have a site, and I want the user to be able to view their liked articles.  I want this to be included in the user api view that is already set up.  I have tried the `tracks = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)`that is in the drf docs yet this didn't work.  I have also tried the following:

```
    from rest_framework import serializers

from articles.models import Article, CustomUser,FavoriteArticles


class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('title', 'content')
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = '__all__'

class FavoriteArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FavoriteArticles
        fields = '__all__'

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fav_title = FavoriteArticleSerializer(read_only=False)
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = 'username, git, email, fav_article, fav_title, homepage'
```

and my models:

```
from django.db import models
# users/models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
import uuid



class ProgrammingLanguage(models.Model):
    programming_language = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=False, primary_key=True, default="React")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.programming_language

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25, primary_key=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    usedfor = models.TextField()
    url=models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    article_programming_language = models.ForeignKey(ProgrammingLanguage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="article_programming_language", default="react")
    score = models.IntegerField(max_length=5, null=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    git = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    homepage = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    user_programming_language = models.ForeignKey(ProgrammingLanguage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="most_used_programming_language", default="react")
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)


class FavoriteArticles(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    fav_title = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='fav_title')
    reasons_liked = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user", default="tom" )
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s: %s' % (self.fav_title, self.reasons_liked)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood what [`related_name`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for-in-django) means. It specifies how you would access a model from its reverse relationship. So I'd recommend you remove it from fields in your `FavoriteArticles` model and use the default Django already provides (in this case `favoritearticles_set`):

```
class FavoriteArticles(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    fav_title = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reasons_liked = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="tom")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s: %s' % (self.fav_title, self.reasons_liked)
```

This way, you can access favorite articles of a user via `my_user.favoritearticles_set.all()`. Then, you can change your `UserSerializer` to include a `liked_articles` field which is populated from the `favoritearticles_set` reverse relationship to a user's `FavoriteArticles` using a [`source`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) attribute:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    liked_articles = FavoriteArticleSerializer(source='favoritearticles_set', many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        # explicitly include other fields as required
        fields = ('username', 'git', 'user_programming_language', 'liked_articles')
```

Note that we've made this a `read_only` field, so it will only get populated if you perform a GET request.

Comment: You're answer worked liked a charm.  Thanks.  Can you just explain what this is?  source='favoritearticles_set'

Comment: @lakerskill `source` specifies which model field should be used for this serializer field. In this specific case, we're saying that we want to use the reverse relation field `favoritearticles_set` of the user model. This is a field that Django gives us by default because we defined a foreign key field to `CustomUser` in the `FavoriteArticles` model.