# Django template if choice field

Tags: python, django, templates

im currently trying to figure out how i can check if a status does apply to a users request or not.

models.py

```
class CategoryRequests(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = StatusField()
    STATUS = Choices('Waiting', 'Rejected', 'Accepted')
```

views.py

```
def view_profile_categoy_requests_accepted(request, pk=None):
    if pk:
        user = get_user_model.objects.get(pk=pk)
    else:
        user = request.user
    args = {'user': user}
    return render(request, 'myproject/category_request_accepted.html', args)
```

But at the template this seems to be wrong.

template.html

```
{% if user.categoryrequests.status == 'Waiting' %}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the value of `status`? Can you do `{{ user.categoryrequests.status }}` to see what it outputs?

Comment: seems to be empty, do i really have to process this at the views.py?
And if so, how?

Comment: You can process it anywhere, but if it's empty then it won't ever match with `'Waiting'`.

Comment: its written at the database but i have no clue why i'm not able to access that field :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the problem -- `user.categoryrequests`. If you haven't set a `related_name` on the foreignkey field, you can't do reverse lookups like this.

You've two options:

**1.** EITHER use `user.categoryrequests_set` to get reverse foreignkey from user.

**2.** OR, set a `related_name` on the foreignkey to `categoryrequests` and then you can do reverse lookup the way you're currently doing.

---

See the docs about doing [reverse lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

Comment: {% if user.categoryrequests.cr_status == Waiting %} and
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cr_status')

does the job. thx everybody :D

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `related_name` argument to `ForeignKey` in your models.py:

```
class CategoryRequests(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='status')
    status = StatusField()
    STATUS = Choices('Waiting', 'Rejected', 'Accepted')
```

Then in the template something like:

```
{% if user.status.STATUS == 'Waiting' %}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2642645/2052575) explains more about `related_name`