# Django Templating filter Object in Status X

Tags: django, templates, filter

i want to display all objects of category_request in status Rejected, but it seems that im doing something wrong here. I'm quite new to Django/Python, if somebody has an idea please scream it out to me ;)

models.py

```
class CategoryRequests(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='status', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Title")
    description = models.TextField(max_length=175, null=True, blank=True)
    cover = fields.ImageField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        validators=[default_image_size, default_image_file_extension],
        upload_to=get_file_path_user_uploads,
        dependencies=[FileDependency(processor=ImageProcessor(format='JPEG', quality=99, scale={'max_width': 1000, 'max_height': 1000}))])
    published_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    status = StatusField()
    STATUS = Choices('Waiting', 'Rejected', 'Accepted')
```

views.py

```
def view_profile_category_requests_rejected(request, pk=None):
    if pk:
        user = get_user_model.objects.get(pk=pk)
        category_request = CategoryRequests(pk=pk)
    else:
        user = request.user
    args = {'user': user,
            'category_request': category_request}
    return render(request, 'myproject/_from_home/category_request_rejected_from_home.html', args)
```

Template.html

```
{% if user.category_request.status == Rejected %}
        {% if user.category_request_set.count == 0 %}
            <div class="centercontentfloat">
                <div class="card border-primary mb-3">
                    <div class="card-header">No Post's available yet  ...</div>
                    <div class="card-body text-primary">
                        <p class="card-text">You did not created any posts at all, go ahead and tell the world what it use to know!</p>
                        <a href="{% url 'post_new' %}">
                            <button class="btn btn-dark" type="submit">Create new Post <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% else %}
            <h4 class="sub-titel-home">Rejected Request(s):</h4>
            <table class="table center class-three-box">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="font-size: small">Title</th>
                    <th style="font-size: small">Comment's</th>
                    <th style="font-size: small">Created</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {% for category_request in user.category_request_set.all %}
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="{% url 'category_request_detail' pk=category_request.pk %}">{{ category_request.title }}</a></td>
                        <td>{{ category_request.comment_set.count }}</td>
                        <td>{{ category_request.published_date }}</td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
    <h1 class="center">Rejected-Status filter does not work</h1>
    {% endif %}

    </div>
```

So how do i filter only category requests in status rejected and display it in my Table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does the `category_request` from `{% if category_request.status_set == Rejected %}` originates from?

Comment: from the view and at models.py it should be related_name='status'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53980029/django-template-if-choice-field/53980461#53980461

Comment: but this does not answers where `category_request` is coming from, it is not even in the linked question.

Comment: I updates my view but now i get: "local variable 'category_request' referenced before assignment"

Comment: that is because you did not define the `category_request` in the `else` branch.

Comment: So far so good, im still now able to get objects listed in my template, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Business logic*, such as *filtering*, etc. is typically written at the *view* level, *not* at the *template* level. In fact this is one of the reasons why Django restricted the template syntax, such that making function calls, etc. is quite hard.

What we basically want is all the `CategoryRequests` where the `author` is the `User` with the given primary key `pk`, and where the `status` is `Rejected`. We can obtain this with a filter like:

```
CategoryRequests.objects.filter(author__pk=pk, status='Rejected')
```

So we can define such queryset in the view:

```
def view_profile_category_requests_rejected(request, pk=None):
    if pk:
        category_requests = CategoryRequests.objects.filter(
            author__pk=pk, status='Rejected'
        )
    else:
        category_requests = CategoryRequests.objects.filter(
            author=request.user, status='Rejected'
        )
    return render(
        request,
        'myproject/_from_home/category_request_rejected_from_home.html', 
        {'category_requests': category_requests}
    )
```

in the template, we can then iterate over `category_requests`:

```
{% if not category_requests %}
    <div class="centercontentfloat">
        <div class="card border-primary mb-3">
            <div class="card-header">No Posts available yet...</div>
            <div class="card-body text-primary">
                <p class="card-text">You did not created any posts at all, go ahead and tell the world what it use to know!</p>
                <a href="{% url 'post_new' %}">
                    <button class="btn btn-dark" type="submit">Create new Post <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% else %}
    <h4 class="sub-titel-home">Rejected Request(s):</h4>
    <table class="table center class-three-box">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="font-size: small">Title</th>
            <th style="font-size: small">Comment's</th>
            <th style="font-size: small">Created</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for category_request in category_requests %}
            <tr>
                <td><a href="{% url 'category_request_detail' pk=category_request.pk %}">{{ category_request.title }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ category_request.comment_set.count }}</td>
                <td>{{ category_request.published_date }}</td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you for this simple and understandable answere :D

Comment: Now i also dont need  related_name='status' anymore, Top!