# Django ForeignKey related_name='+'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

What does `'+'` value mean, when passed for `related_name` parameter of `models.ForeignKey()`?

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.ForeignKey(related_name='+')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is \`related\_name\` used for in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for-in-django)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [Django documentation on **`related_name`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) says:

> If you’d prefer Django **not to create a backwards relation**, set `related_name` to `'+'` or end it with `'+'`.

If you thus have two models `A` and `B`, then by setting a `ForeignKey` from `A` to `B`, Django will add a manager to `B` to obtain all related `A`s for a given `B`, but by setting it to `'+'`, we disable that behavior.