# Foreign key to user model not working as expected

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I have a `django` project with a custom user model.

I have this `Subscriptions` model that uses the custom user model as its foreign key.

```
class Subscriptions(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    app_subscriptions = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.app_subscriptions
```

But if I try to retreive all users `app_subscriptions` with `..app_subscriptions_set.all()` it always returns with the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'CustomUser' object has no attribute 'app_subscriptions_set'
```

I have the same type of model in use here:

```
from django.db import models

class Software(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Version(models.Model):
    version = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    software = models.ForeignKey(Software, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.version
```

And on this model I have no issues querying for all software versions with `...version_set.last()`.

Anyone have any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is `subscriptions_set`, *not* `app_subscriptions_set`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `user_instance.subscriptions_set.all()` instead of `.app_subscriptions_set.all()`.

The default accesor is the model name, all lowercase, and appends `_set`. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) about it, or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2642645/9225671).

Your model `Version` is just like that:

```
software_instance.version_set.all()
```