# Best way to filter queryset by counting number of ForeignKey in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 models, ChatRoom and Message:

Model ChatRoom:

```
class ChatRoom(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='chat_creator', null=True, blank=True)
    with_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='room_user_with')
```

Model Message:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    chat = models.ForeignKey(ChatRoom, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='message_room')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='message_user')
    content = models.TextField()
```

I want to filter ChatRoom queryset by getting ChatRoom which have more than 10 messages in it.

What is the best way to do this? Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ChatRoom.objects.annotate(cnt=Count('message_room')).filter(cnt__gt=20)
```

Your `related_name`s are misleading :); they should refer to the model containing the foreign key from the perspective of the model the foreign key refers to, e.g. `chat_messages` and `user_messages`.

Comment: Here's [some more reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for-in-django) on `related_name`.