# Django REST framework - reverse ForeignKey relations

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-2.2

I have the following three models structured around the premise of the Survey.

```
class Survey(models.Model):
   ...
   id = models.UUIDField(_('Id'), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False,)
   name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=120, blank=True, unique=True)
   slug = models.SlugField(_('Slug'), max_length=120, blank=True, unique=True)
   description = models.TextField(_('Description'), blank=True)
   ...
```

Each Survey can have multiple questions `SurveyQuestion`:

```
class SurveyQuestion(models.Model):
    ...
    survey = models.ForeignKey('surveys.Survey', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,)
```

And each SurveyQuestion can have multiple answers `SurveyQuestionAnswer`:

```
class SurveyQuestionAnswer(models.Model):
    ...
    survey_question = models.ForeignKey('surveys.SurveyQuestion', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,)
```

For the sake of brevity, imagine my Survey serializers as being as simple as possible:

```
class SurveySerialializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Survey
        fields = ('__all__')
```

Effectively, what I have is the following:

```
class Survey(APIView):
    """
        Survey GET request endpoint: fetches Survey
    """
    permission_classes = User

    def get(self, request, survey_slug):

        survey = Survey.objects.get(slug=survey_slug)

        serializer = SurveySerializer(survey)

        response = get_hug_response(message='Organisation Active Survey Fetched Successfully', data=serializer.data)
        return Response(data=response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

But, as you could all probably tell, the corresponding `surveys.get('slug')` fetch only returns the fields in the `Survey` model. Ideally, I would like to have some sort of fetch for each `SurveyQuestion`, and within that nested the `SurveyQuestionAnswers`

Any pro-tips and pointers would be most appreciated.

I have tried a few things, that only throw errors. I'm struggling to know what this type of API relationship is called in DRF so I can't find appropriate example guides to base the same principles from...

Relevant versions:

```
Django==2.2.1
djangorestframework==3.9.3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two serializers, **`SurveyQuestionAnswerSerializer`** and **`SurveyQuestionSerializer`**

```
class SurveyQuestionAnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SurveyQuestionAnswer
        fields = '__all__'


class SurveyQuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    survey_questionanswers = SurveyQuestionAnswerSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source="surveyquestionanswer_set")

    class Meta:
        model = SurveyQuestion
        fields = '__all__'


class SurveySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    survey_questions = SurveyQuestionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source="surveyquestion_set")

    class Meta:
        model = Survey
        fields = '__all__'
```

For more info,
1. [**What is `related_name` used for in Django?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for-in-django)
2. [**DRF Serializer's `source` argument**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source)

Comment: Amazing, worked first time. Easy when you know how! Could you explain what the `source` sets are doing....

Comment: I have updated with some related links, hope it will convey the idea :)

Comment: Hmmm, the link for the `source` argument doesn't specify what `_set` means. Can I assume the set belongs to the parent model instance?

Comment: The first reference conveying what  **_set** is

Comment: `_set` here is using the standard Django related manager (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager)