# Django - Am I in the right direction for creating the models of my Phone Review application?

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner in Django. I am building    a   data    model   for a Django app, named PhoneReview. It will store reviews related to the   latest  mobile  phone.  It's table  should  include:

a. Brand    – details   on  brand,  such    as, name,   origin, manufacturing   since,  etc

b. Model    – details   on  model,  such    as, model   name,   launch  date,   platform,   etc

c. Review   – review    article on  the mobile  phone   and date    published,  etc

d. Many-to-many relationship between Review and Model.

Here are my codes in models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

# Create your models here.
class Brand(models.Model):
    brandName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manufacturingSince = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='null')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.brandName

class PhoneModel(models.Model):
    modelName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    launchDate = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.modelName

class Review(models.Model):
    model_name_many_to_many = models.ManyToManyField(PhoneModel)
    reviewArticle = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    datePublished = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, default='null')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.reviewArticle
```

Are my codes correct? Am I in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use camelCase in model fields. Use snake_case. Second thing is, when you want field to be default 'null', just use null=True, blank=True(optional value).
I've also provided related_name to your ManyToManyField, so you can use PhoneModelInstance.reviews.all() to get your all reviews for this specific Phone model. For large fields containing text, use TextField.

## Edit

I've also added foreign key in PhoneModel which points to the Brand.

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

# Create your models here.
class Brand(models.Model):
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manufacturing_since = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.brand_name

class PhoneModel(models.Model):
    brand_fk = models.ForeignKey(Brand)
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    launch_date = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model_name

class Review(models.Model):
    phone_model = models.ManyToManyField(PhoneModel, related_name='reviews')
    review_article = models.TextField()
    date_published = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.review_article
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I have a question regarding phone_model = models.ManyToManyField(PhoneModel, related_name='reviews'). So, basically, this line allows me to use all the variables of PhoneModel class in the Review class. Am I right? And what is the purpose of related_name='reviews' ?

Comment: Review instance example:
review_obj.phone_model.all() - returns all PhoneModel objects related to this review.

PhoneModel instance example:
phone_model_obj.reviews.all() - returns all Review objects related with this PhoneModel. For related name explaination, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for-in-django