# Django Rest Nested Relationship is not working

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

This is the defined models:

```
class User(models.Model):

        name        = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        status      = models.IntegerField(default=1)
        created_at  = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date created', auto_now_add=True)
        updated_at  = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date updated', auto_now_add=True)



        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

class UserInfo(models.Model):

    user_id       = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True)
    phone        = models.IntegerField()

    status               = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    created_at           = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date created', auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at           = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date updated', auto_now_add=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return '%d: ' % (self.user_id)
```

These is how the serializer looks like:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    info = UserInfoSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:

        model  = User
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'status', 'info']
```

I am supposed to get **info** key in the response. But while id, name & status keys are returned, info key is missing.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`source`** argument,

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    info = UserInfoSerializer(read_only=True, many=True, source='userinfo_set')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'status', 'info']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but it doesn't working for me.

Comment: Why `userinfoset`? From where that name come from? It refers to what? I need to understand why you write the name like this to try to name my own fields here.

Comment: it is the **`related_name`**. Read more here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for-in-django

Answer (score 0):

You can use related_name in the model for ForaignKey. Something like:

```
user_id       = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True, related_name="info")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it olny displaying the pk of the UserInfo. What can i do to display all the  value of the UserInfo (such as 'status','created_at')???

Comment: You will need to put that fields in UserInfoSerializer

Comment: I put `related_name` in my ForeingKey field on my model, but it doesn't work, the fields continues not showing up.

Comment: @André have you put it in the serializer as well?