# The Django problem with "set.all" returns nothing in the template

Tags: python, django

Hi Stackoverflow people,
You will help with the following.

My urls:

```
path('Autorow/szczegoły/<int:id>/', views.Szczegoly_autorzy, name='Szczegoly_autorzy'),
```

My views:

```
def Szczegoly_autorzy(request, id):
   autor = get_object_or_404(Author, pk=id)
   return render(request, 'Szczegoly_autorzy.html', {'autor': autor})
```

My models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
   zdjecie_autora = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=True, upload_to='zdjecia_autorow')
   imie_nazwisko = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
   data_urodzenia = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
   informacje = models.TextField()


def __str__(self):
    return self.imie_nazwisko



class Book(models.Model):
    tytul = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    autor = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    opis = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    rok_wydania = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    zdjecie = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=True, upload_to='zdjecia_ksiazek')



def __str__(self):
    return self.tytul
```

Templates:

```
        {% for ksiazki in autor.ksiazki_set.all %}
                    <li><a href="{%  url 'Szczegoly_ksiazki' ksiazki.id %}">"{{ ksiazki }}"</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
```

I don't see the list of books the author wrote in my templates.
This is my second app and it works in the first one, but I don't know where I'm making a mistake here.
Help me

Comment: Consider using English language in your code as field/variable names. Naming your fields/variables in Polish is not good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `autor.book_set.all` instead of `autor.ksiazki_set.all`

For more info, go through this SO post, [What is `related_name` used for in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for-in-django)

Comment: Thanks so much I tired of such a detail