# Django Foreignkey reverse access when parent model has multiple Foreignkeys

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using the standard Django User-model and wrote this cutom Model:

```
class Messages(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="sender", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="receiver", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Now, given a User-object `user` i want to access all the Messages he either sent or received. I tried: `user.messages_set.all()` but i am getting the following Error: `'User' object has no attribute 'messages_set'`.
How do i fix this?

Thanks for your Answers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is \`related\_name\` used for in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for-in-django)

Comment: @kyore Partially. Is there a way for getting a queryset that contains all the objects where user is either the sender or the receiver? using backwards-accessing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cause that you defined `related_name='sender'`. If you use related name, you must use it for backward queries. You can use this code for access your use messages:

```
user.sender.all()
```

You can use more detail about related_name [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

Comment: Is there a way to get a queryset containing all the objects here user is either the sender or the receiver? using backwards-access?

Comment: If you want to get messages of a user that he can be receiver or sender, you can use this query: Messages.objects.filter(Q(sender=user)|Q(receiver=user))