# Display user's posts in their profile on django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

I have been trying to make the profile page of a user have the user's posts but everytime I run my code nothing shows up only the user's username and user's email. I've tried multiple ways to make it work but somehow it doesn't. I think the profile.html has the error in it.

views.py

```
    def profile(request, pk=None):
        if pk:
            post_owner = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
            user_posts=Post.objects.filter(posti=request.user)

        else:
            post_owner = request.user
            user_posts=Post.objects.filter(posti=request.user)
        return render(request, 'profile.html', {'post_owner': post_owner, 'user_posts': user_posts})
```

models.py

```
    class Post(models.Model):
        text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        posti = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/images', null=True, blank="True")
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='imageuser', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=2)
```

profile.html

```
    <div class="content-section">
      <div class="media">
        <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
        <div class="media-body">
          <h2 class="account-heading">{{ post_owner.username }}</h2>
          <p class="text-secondary">{{ post_owner.email }}</p>
        </div>
        {% for Post in user_posts %}
          <li class="list-group-item">{{ Post.text }}
            <a href="{% url 'profile_pk' pk=image.user.pk %}">{{ Post.user }}</a>
            {% if Post.posti %}
              <img src="{{ image.posti.url }}" alt="image here" style="max-width: 300px; max-height: 300px">
            {% endif %}
            {% if Post.user == user %}
              <div class="float-right">
                <form action="delete_image/{{ image.id }}/" action="post">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
                </form>
              </div>
            {% endif %}
          </li>     
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is with the line:

```
user_posts=Post.objects.filter(posti=request.user)
```

To get the posts from the logged in user you will need to use this:

```
user_posts=Post.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

and to get the posts from the selected user you will need to do this:

```
user_posts=Post.objects.filter(user_id=pk)
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: A NoReverseMatch error is because there is not a url in your `urls.py` which matches what you have looked for. This is most likely due to this code: `{% url 'profile_pk' pk=image.user.pk %}`. This should probably be `{% url 'profile_pk' pk=Post.user.pk %}` since `image` isn't actually defined anywhere in your template.

Comment: Your code is working but the user's profile page shows the posts from the loged in user and not from the selected user.

Comment: I think there is an if statement mising on the profile.html that selects the posts from the user that is being checked.

Comment: Ah, okay. I have updated my answer to add more clarity on how to get posts from different users.

Comment: Tim, just one question. When I try to delete an image it doesn't work on the profile view but it does on the imagelist view which shows all the images from all the users, if you need to see some more code like the imagelist view or the delete_post let me know please.

Answer (score 0):

You are querying the wrong column:

```
user_posts=Post.objects.filter(posti=request.user)
```

`posti` is an `ImageField`. You actually want to query the `user` field:

```
user_posts=Post.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

That being said, you don't need any of these queries in your view. You can simply make use of your `related_name`, i.e.:

```
{% for Post in post_owner.imageuser.all %}
```

Comment: soory,what do you mean with related name?

Comment: It's in your model, `related_name='imageuser'` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for-in-django