# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'students' into field. Choices are: exam, id, student, student_id, subject, test

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am building an online class, where students can check their result when they login to their account, I do not know how to go about querying the result from the database so as to be able to generate the result posted by the teacher for each students. Please how do I write the views.py ?

I did some things but there was an error. This is my code:

```
class Result(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Students, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    test = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    exam = models.FloatField(null=True, blank= True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=SUBJECT, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-student"]

    def get_total(self):
        return self.exam + self.test

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student.first_name


class Students(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='top')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='top')
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    email = models.EmailField()
    class_choice = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=CLASS)
    last_accessed = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["last_name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.last_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('students-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, we do like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#saving-foreignkey-and-manytomanyfield-fields)

```
class Result(models.Model):
   student = models.ForeignKey(Students, related_name='results')

class Student(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='top')


s1 = Student.objects.get(id=1)
res = s1.results.all()
```

Comment: This is what i saw AttributeError: 'Result' object has no attribute 'all'

Comment: student = get_object_or_404(Students, id=id)
results = Result.objects.filter(students=student), how can i use this correctly

Comment: I added `related_name` in model. If you didn't have it, you query should  be `s1.result_set.all()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for-in-django

Comment: `s = get_object_or_404(Student, id=id) res = s.results.all()` or `res = Result.objects.filter(student=s)`

Comment: I have been able to get it into the context data, thanks for your time