# How to get data from other table in django with Foreign Key(New to Django)

Tags: python, django

I have Two table MeterDetail,EnergyData

```
class MeterDetail(models.Model):
    metername = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    meter_id = models.IntegerField()
    meter_type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    meter_purpose = models.CharField(max_length=20)#auto_now_add=True
    meter_location = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'meterdetails'
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.meter_id)
class EnergyData(models.Model):
    last_kwh = models.FloatField()
    date_time_recorded = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)#auto_now_add=True
    meter_id = models.ForeignKey(MeterDetail,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="meter_details")

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'energydata'
        get_latest_by = "date_time_recorded"
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.last_kwh)
```

I want to get data from second table using first object.
I tried in shell
 t= MeterDetail.objects.get(meter_id=1)
am unable to read this below one
t.energydata_set.all()

giving error: AttributeError: 'MeterDetail' object has no attribute 'energydata_set'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use **`t.meter_details.all()`** instead of `t.energydata_set.all()`

Here, the **`meter_details`** is the ***related_name*** to get the reverse objects.

- [**What is `related_name` used for in Django?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for-in-django)