# creating django model for review gives this msg

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

When i try to create the reviews table, i get the the following error message. The models.py and error message in the terminal is mentioned below.

models.py

```
class reviews(models.Model):
    reviewee = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reviewer = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    review = models.TextField()
    rating = models.FloatField()

class Person(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    pwd = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

terminal output

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
pfapp.reviews.reviewee: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'reviews.reviewee' clashes with reverse accessor for 'reviews.reviewer'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'reviews.reviewee' or 'reviews.reviewer'.
pfapp.reviews.reviewer: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'reviews.reviewer' clashes with reverse accessor for 'reviews.reviewee'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'reviews.reviewer' or 'reviews.reviewee'.

System check identified 2 issues (0 silenced).
```

The logic behind my models is that on person can review another person. Also, when either reviewer or reviewee is deleted from the table, the review should also be deleted.

i hope you got my idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do and then migrate:

```
reviewee = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
reviewer = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="reviewer", null=True)
```

Now, on reverse you can get *reviewee* from `person.reviews` which is by default. And, get *reviewer* from `person.reviewer`. Have a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for-in-django) for greater understanding.