# How To Access Many Field In One-To-Many Relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, relationship

I have two different user types, Teachers and Students. My students have a one-to-many relationship with a Teacher (a student can have one teacher / a teacher can have many students). I am able to access a student's Teacher in templates like this `user.student.teacher`, but I dont know how to access a list of a Teacher's Students?

- From a teacher's profile page id like to print a list of their students.

```
# override default User model
class User(AbstractUser):
    user_type = models.CharField(choices=USER_TYPES, max_length=255, default='student')

class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django automatically allows you to access other way and by default names manager `student_set`. Note, model name followed by `_set`. You can override this name by setting `related_name` in `ForeignKey`.

Learn in depth [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference)

- You can query, `teacher.student_set.all()` this will show teacher's all students.
- You can also use `related_name` like this,

```
class Student(models.Model):
    ...
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True, related_name='students')
```

and then query like this, `teacher.students.all()`

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
user.teacher.student_set.all()
```

Reference:

- [What is `related_name` used for in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for-in-django)