# How do I assign two foreign keys to two fields in one model in Django?

Tags: django

So I have Article model and Category model. And below are my models.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    category_kor = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="책")
    category_eng = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="book")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class Article(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()

    category_eng = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = '', null=True, default=None) 
    category_kor = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = '', null=True, default=None)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=10000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

So I've done some research and noticed that I have to do something with the `related_name` but I cannot fully understand and apply it to my model. Please help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, Instead of using same value in related_field, if you use different value it should work.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    category_eng = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'rel_category', null=True, default=None) 
    category_kor = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'related_category_kor', null=True, default=None)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=10000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: follow this to know more about related_field https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for-in-django

Comment: Thanks. By related_field you mean related_name, right?