# Filtering Annotations in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I am annotating a QuerySet with a Count, but i only want to count certain objects, so I'm using a filter:

```
    objects = Parent.objects.annotate(num_children=Count('child',filter=Q(deleted_at=None)))
```

The Filter is not working, the count for every object seems to be ignoring the filter, i.e. it also counts the children which have

```
deleted_at != None
```

The **model**:

```
class child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('project.Parent', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Does anybody have a solution?
Thanks in adcance.

**Edit**

Using `Q(deleted_at__isnull=True)` is not working either. Strangely with `~Q(deleted_at=None)` I get the expected Behaviour...

Comment: try deleted_at__isnull=True

Comment: @vpdiongzon Thats not working either. Strangely, when filtering ~Q(deleted_at=None), i get the expected behaviour

Comment: can you try to add related_name='child' on your parent field

Comment: @vpdiongzon not working either...

Comment: Can you add little more info of your Database, Django version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

When you filtering with **`Q(...)`** objects, the lookups must be provided with respect to the **`Parent`** model.

So, it should be **`filter=Q(child__deleted_at=None)`** instead of `filter=Q(deleted_at=None)`

```
objects = Parent.objects.annotate(
    num_children=Count('child', filter=Q(child__deleted_at=None))
)
```

---

### Long Answer

To reproduce the error/issue behaviour, I created two simple models as below,

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'parent_table'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='children')
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'child_table'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.parent} -- {self.deleted_at}'
```

**Notes:**

1. I have set `related_name='children'`, which more "meaningful" while querying reverse relations. If you're not familiar with the `related_name`, read more

   a. [What is `related_name` in Django -- (SO Post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for-in-django)

   b. [Following backwards relationship -- (Django doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)

   c. [ForeignKey.related_name -- (Django doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
2. I have set [`db_table`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#db-table), coz, I am going to query the database using RawSQL for some reason. You don't have to set it.

Now, I have populated the database with a few dummy data and the result is as follows,

[image: Joined table view]

Then I opened my Django shell and run the following query,

```
In [2]: from django.db.models import Q,Count                                                                                                                                                                       

In [3]: parent_objects = Parent.objects.annotate( 
   ...:     num_children=Count('children', filter=Q(children__deleted_at=None)) 
   ...: )                                                                                                                                                                                                          

In [4]: for parent in parent_objects: 
   ...:     print(parent.id, '--', parent.name, ' :: ', parent.num_children) 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                            
1 -- parent-1  ::  2
2 -- parent-2  ::  0
3 -- parent-3  ::  1
```

OR,
the raw SQL view,

[image: annotate result]