# count total object in foreign key - drf

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i want to count comments for every single Post

in models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    liked_by = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='liked_by')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']

class Comment(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']
```

in serializers.py:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = '__all__'

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #comments = CommentSerializer()
    user = UserSerializers()
    total_likes = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    liked_by = SimpleUserSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    total_comments = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('body','date','user', 'total_likes', 'liked_by','total_comments')

    def get_total_likes(self, instance):
        return instance.liked_by.count()

    def get_total_comments(self, instance):
        return instance.comments.count()
```

when i run this code, it shows, **AttributeError: 'Post' object has no attribute 'comments'**.

how do i count comments of a post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't configured the ***related_name***, Django uses the default `related_name` and hence you should access the reveres FK using **`comment_set`** instead of `comments`

Thus, the **`get_total_comments(...)`** method should look like

```
def get_total_comments(self, instance):
    return instance.comment_set.count()
```

#### Reference

- [What is `related_name` used for in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for-in-django)

Comment: sir, it's not working. showing, **django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "fb_comment" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "fb_comment" WHERE "fb_com...** my app name is **fb**

Comment: sir, it works. i rename the model name. but did not makemigrations