# Issues getting primary key django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I started to learn Django and I decided to create a blog to check my skills and train myself with an actual project.
In my models.py there is two models :

```py
class Article (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    is_draft = models.BooleanField(default = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    comment_author = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    comment = models.TextField()
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment_author
```

I want to display all the title and content of every articles and the numbers of comment  , to do so I used a ListView.
views.py :

```py
class ArticleListView (ListView):
    context_object_name = 'articles'
    model = models.Article
    # print(models.Article.objects.get(pk=1).models.Comment_set.all())

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
         context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
         context['title'] = models.Comment.objects.get(pk=1) # I don't know how to change this value 
         context['id'] = self.model.id 
         return context
```

article_list.html :

```html
{% for article in articles %}
    <h2>{{ article.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ article.content }}</p>
    <h5>Id of article is {{ id }}</h5>
    <h6>{{ title }}</h6>
    {% endfor %}
```

I wanted to use count() on Comment so I get the numbers of comments by post. To get the list of article's comments I thought that I need the pk for each article so I can find the number of comment but it doesn't work.
Do you have any ideas how I can figure this out ?

**Also when I try to get the id in get_context_data() [in views.py] I got something like <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x7fead2213fd0> instead of a numbers do you know a way to get an actual numbers ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of all articles and their comments in the template without having to overwrite `get_context_data()`. You can pass a `related_name` to the ForeignKey relationship to specify it but if you don't Django creates one automatically for you. The automatically created default for you will be: `comment_set`. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) for the documentation.

article_list.html

```
{% for article in articles %}
    <h2>{{ article.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ article.content }}</p>

    <p>Total comments: {{ article.comment_set.count }}</p>
    {% for comment in article.comment_set.all %}
        <p>{{ comment.author }}</p>
        <p>{{ comment.comment }}</p>
    {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
```

I would recommend setting a `related_name` though and then your model and template code will be:

```
article = models.ForeignKey(Article,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comments")

{% for comment in article.comments %}
{% endfor %}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for-in-django) is a related Stack Overflow post as well if you want to read more about it.