# Passing Editable Fields as validated_data method of Django-Rest-Framework Serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm writing a contacts service in Django-REST-Framework.
I have a `Contact` Model and a `PhoneNumber` Model which has a foreignKey field that shows which contact does it belong to.
Here are my models:

```
class ContactModel(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)

class PhoneNumber(BaseModel):
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=VERY_SHORT_STRING_SIZE, blank=False)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=SHORT_STRING_SIZE, blank=False, null=False)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=NORMAL_STRING_SIZE, blank=True, default='')
    related_contact = models.ForeignKey(to='ContactModel', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to make a `CRUD` api for my Contacts. I have a `ModelViewSet` and a `ModelSerializer` for that. serializer codes is as follows:

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    phonenumber_set = PhoneSerializer(many=True, required=False)
        class Meta:
            model = ContactModel
            fields = '__all__'

class PhoneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PhoneNumber
        fields = ['id', 'country_code', 'phone_number', 'label']
```

As it's been specified [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations) I should override update and create methods in order to update and create PhoneNumbers of my Contact.

The problem is that if I override those functions I have to use them like this:

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    def create(self, validated_data):
        # some code for creating both PhoneNumber and Contact


    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # some code for updating both PhoneNumber and Contact
```

and unfortunately, **'validated_data' argument doesn't bring the 'id' of my PhoneNumber objects**, because 'id' fields are AutoFields and AutoFields will be read_only in DRF (it's explained [Here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-read-only-fields)).

Is there a way for me to have access to my 'id' field in my update method? (kinda need it badly)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over `instance.phonenumber_set.all()` at your `update()` method and you will have complete access to those related objects.

for ex:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    for phonenumber in instance.phonenumber_set.all():
        # do what you want with phonenumber, like phonenumber.id
```

`instance` is the current object that is being updated at your serializer and it is being passed as an argument to `update()` as you can see, so you can access and do anything with it as you normally do.

Tip:

It's better to add `related_name` to `related_contact` to make it better readability, also change `related_contact` to `contacts`. `related_name` is used for selecting reverse relations as we did just like now.

I think it's better to do so:

```
contacts = models.ForeignKey(to='ContactModel', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='phonenumbers')
```

so instead of using `phonenumber_set` it will be `phonenumbers` for better readability but the name with `_map` still valid too, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2642645/4984493) for more info about `related_name`

Comment: Don't think this could help. I need to have one of my PhoneNumbers id, not my instance id.

Comment: sorry, I thought you were asking about the object itself. I have updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: I truly appreciate your help, but I have to say that unfortunately this is not the answer, again. by using "instance.phonenumbers_set.all()" I will get all phone_numbers currently stored in database for my contact. and what I want, is the passed ID of to-be-updated phone_numbers, which have just been sent from client.

Comment: okay, now I get your goal, but, can you share your request data? generally `instance` is the object that will be updated so you should look there but let's see.