# "Object has no property _set" in Django

Tags: python, reactjs, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Can't figure out where my mistake is. Not able to map through to display the list of blog comments. I'm using Django and react. From the code below, I tried to assess each blog post with comments using foreign key. But I'm not able to get the comment property from the blog. If I do something like `{blog.title}` I get the title of the blog back on the browser. Since comments are associated with each post I try to get different properties of comment from the blog object (just as I specified in the code below) but the value I'm getting is `undefined`. And have the following blog post and blog comment models:

```py
class BlogComment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="post_comment",  null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="user_comment", null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    ...
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And the serializers for both models are:

```py
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogComment
        fields = '__all__'

class BlogPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comments = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = "__all__"

    def get_comments(self, obj):
        comments = obj.comment_set.all()
        serializer = CommentSerializer(comments, many=True)
        return serializer.data
```

The endpint of comment is `path('posts/<str:pk>/comment/', CreateCommentView, name="create-comment"),`.

The endpoint is working. I'm able to add comment to posts both from the front end. The error comes when I try to map through the
comments for each post. Get the error: `AttributeError: 'BlogPost' object has no attribute 'comment_set'`.

Here is the code I'm using to map through to display all the blogs of a particular post in the blog details page in react. I'm assess each blog there:

```js
<h2>{blog.title}</h2>
<img src={blog.image} />
<div variant='flush'>
                    {blog.comments.map((comment) => (
                        <div key={comment.id}>
                            <strong>{comment.name}</strong>            
                            <p>{comment.dateCreated}</p>
                            <p>{comment.comment}</p>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
```

Here is the code I'm using to map through to display all the blogs of a particular post in the blog details page in react. If I do not map the error does not come up and I'm able to add comment. However, in order to display the comments under each blog post I map through. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `post_comment`:

```py
comments = obj.post_comment.all()
```

You declared it here:

```py
post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="post_comment",  null=True)
```

`related_name` is used as a name for Django relation. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for).

But changing `post_comment` with something else would be a better solution for me.

Comment: Thank you @Yevgeniy Kosmak. After making the change the error did not show up again. Yet the blog comments isn't displaying in the page. The error it's showing now is that it can't map through property of undefined.

Comment: I'm able to add post but when I submit, instead of the comment to display in the page  the page crashes and becomes blank

Comment: @C-Bizz, I believe you should open a new question for that. I'm not experienced with ReactJS. Now you localized the issue on the front-end, and you can ask it with [tag:reactjs] tag.

Comment: Alright, thank you

Comment: @C-Bizz glad to help and good luck :)