# How to save a User as an attribute of a model Django

Tags: django

I am trying to create a Mail function as part of my website, I would like to save the receiving `User` instead of the receiving User's username in the `receiver` part of the `Mail` class, so I don't have to filter the User. This is what I did:

```
class Mail(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, choices=[(u.username, u) for u in User.objects.all()])
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
```

django is giving me this error

```
ERRORS:
mail.Mail.sender: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'mail.Mail.sender' clashes with reverse accessor for 'mail.Mail.receiver'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'mail.Mail.sender' or 'mail.Mail.receiver'.
mail.Mail.receiver: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'mail.Mail.receiver' clashes with reverse accessor for 'mail.Mail.sender'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'mail.Mail.receiver' or 'mail.Mail.sender'.
```

Comment: If in one model you reference same foreign key two or more times you need to set related_name for second and more fields

Answer (score 0):

You need to add related_name attribute. For more information read this post:
[What is related_name used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for)

```
class Mail(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sender')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, choices=[(u.username, u) for u in User.objects.all()], related_name='receiver')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
```