# Django API Fetch data from one table another table through nested Foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

**Does anyone know how to get userprofile detials from 'PersonalDetails' through by using the User table**

Modal Connection flow

***User -> Representative -> PersonalDetails***

Retrive data flows

***User <- Representative <- PersonalDetails***

**Models.py**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseFields):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
     representative =  models.ForeignKey(Representative,blank=True,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Representative(BaseFields):
    personal_details = models.ForeignKey(PersonalDetails,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True,null=True)

class PersonalDetails(models.Model):
    name_en = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    dob = models.DateField()
```

**Serializer.py**

```
class UserProfileSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id','representative')
```

**Views.py**

```
class UserProfileDetailView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    http_method_names = ['get']
    permission_classes = [AllowAny,]
    queryset = PersonalDetails.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {}
        user = User.objects.get(id=kwargs.get('pk'))
        representative_id  = user.representative
        personal_details_id = Representative.objects.get(id=representative_id.id)
        personal_details = PersonalDetails.objects.get(id=personal_details_id.id)
        if personal_details:
            serializer = UserProfileSerializer(personal_details)
            return Response(serializer.data,status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Do not post code as image https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) parameter in `ForeignKey` field:

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseFields):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    representative = models.ForeignKey(Representative, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="representative")

class Representative(BaseFields):
    personal_details = models.ForeignKey(PersonalDetails, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="personal_details")
    role=models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)

class PersonalDetails(models.Model):
    name_en = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    dob = models.DateField()
```

Also, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2642645/5865129) too.